# Locking a table so only one user at a time can update it

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database. One of its table is sometimes updated, but it is critically important, that it cannot be updated simultaneously by several users. When update is finished, another user should be allowed to update the table

Can I limit access for updating table for one user in a moment using just PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, you could lock the table for the duration of a transaction but it would be a really bad idea, for reasons that could go way beyond the scope of just this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, and it's quite normal to do so, but not in the way you're probably thinking.

This is normal and sometimes the simplest way to solve a concurrency issue:

- `BEGIN`
- `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`
- ... do a complicated set of updates/inserts/deletes
- `COMMIT`

but it's only really ok if *you aren't waiting for the user*. You can only have a `LOCK` held on a table during a transaction, and it's a bad idea for many reasons to have long-running transactions that stay open while the user thinks about something. It'll tend to make other parts of the app stall for reasons that aren't apparent to the user, it creates problems with automatic database cleanup processes, it encourages deadlocks, and lots more. Bad idea. Don't do this:

- `BEGIN`
- `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE`
- Wait for the user to tell me what to do next
- Do stuff the user tells me to
- Repeat until the user says they're done
- `COMMIT`

For that, you generally want [*optimistic concurrency control*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control), [advisory locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS), or an application-managed scheme for user lockout from data.